# bash alias starting with pipe doesn't work?

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to create an alias that starts with a pipe.

ex:

```
echo -i "hello\nworld" | grep world
> world
alias gr="| grep"
echo -i "hello\nworld" gr world
> hello
> world gr world
```

I.e, if the alias start with a pipe, aliasing doesn't seem to work properly.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can do this in `zsh` with a "global alias" but get to keep all the pieces when things break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> Aliases  allow  a  string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.

Pipe can't be the first word of a simple command.

Comment: Is there a mechanism like alias but more powerful to get this sort of functionality?

Comment: Nothing that doesn't involve more typing than you are trying to avoid (namely, using `eval` to execute a dynamically constructed command line).

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev, you can use [zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/), then, for example, `gp` expands to `| grep -i` [cheatsheet](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet)

Comment: @joeybaruch thanks for tip. Although I work as a consultant and often work in plain bash environments where I can't install custom packages like zsh, so was looking more of a pure bash kinda thing.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev, I have a similar issue with remote servers I often log into. If you do find a workaround, please do update the solution.

Comment: @joeybaruch I haven't found a solution yet. But I got really good at hitting the pipe symbol on my keyboard, which kinda works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, your alias works. Try `gr` alone and your shell will throw syntax error because of `|` at the beginning of the line. That clearly means the alias works, i.e. it substitutes one string for another **when it is supposed to**.

In your example `gr` is treated as an argument to `echo`, that's why there is no substitution. It wouldn't be, even if there was no pipe inside the alias. The initial pipe symbol doesn't decide whether aliasing occurs or not; however it leads to an error when it does but this error has nothing to do with alias mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

If you can/want to switch shell, you can do this in zsh, by setting the alias as

```
alias -g gr="| grep"
```